# Should I prefer to throw or return when cancellation is requested?

Tags: c#, async-await, cancellation, cancellation-token

Consider the two following approaches to handling cancellation via `CancellationToken`:

```
public async Task DoAllAvailableWork(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    foreach (var job in GetAllAvailableWork())
    {
        await job.Process();

        if (cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested())
            return;
    }
}

public async Task DoAllAvailableWork(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    foreach (var job in GetAllAvailableWork())
    {
        await job.Process();

        cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}
```

In this case `job.Process()` is doing some atomic work that should not or cannot be stopped once it begins, so it does not accept a `CancellationToken`.

Is there any reason to prefer one of these approaches over the other? If yes, which approach should be preferred?

Checking `IsCancellationRequested()` and returning feels cleaner to me, in the sense that throwing implies something has gone wrong, and cancellation is a case that we explicitly planned to handle (that's why we accept the `CancellationToken`). On the other hand, the caller can't necessarily know which approach we'll take, so they have to set up a try/catch for `OperationCancelledException` regardless of which option we choose.

Comment: I agree that returning is cleaner. Using exceptions for control flow and throwing them just for ourselves is nasty (and very expensive). I admit throwing an exception from a deep stack is more convenient but I would use it only if there is no other option. Btw. seeing the votes for closing I think this question fits https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ better

Comment: You're not using a `Task` anywhere and your method has no result, so basically, you can do what you want. As soon as you do return a result the "let's just return" approach obviously can't work anymore and you'll have to throw anyway (unless you really feel comfortable with giving callers a partial or incorrect result and requiring them to check the cancellation token first -- i.e. the "good old" method of having to check error codes for every call, which is exactly what exceptions were designed to avoid).

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Though his DoWork does not use a `Task` it gets the cancellation token, which can be polled in the cycle so he can return as soon as possible if cancellation was requested. I would not throw an exception if I can also return. Of course, the callers need to check the token, too.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Good catch, I was interested in the case where the method is async. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: We also don't know whether the cancellation is a common use-case or an _exceptional one_ (eg. shutdown, timeout, invalid state, etc.). If the latter, I also wouldn't mind to throw an exception. Otherwise, I would rather prepare all the callers to check the cancellation state at the return point(s) from the deeper levels, even if it is a bit inconvenient.

Comment: I am massively in favour of returning as exceptions should be exceptional, not part of the normal control flow as they are expensive and introduce try/catch boilerplate. That said, it depends, I worked on several applications that rely on an operation to complete and adding several layers of `Task<CompletedOrCancelled>` to the hierarchy can become messy if it is not coded with the cancellation in mind upfront. In those cases, throwing an exception will unwind the whole stack and block also the calllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ThrowIfCancellationRequested` was designed for task continuations. Throwing stops the whole continuation chain (with the exception of cancel-handling continuations). An unhandled `OperationCancelledException` in a task will cancel the `Task`'s cancellation token as well (if any).

In your case, there's no `Task`. You are free to define your own interface. But keep in mind that whoever calls your method should also have a way of seeing if your operation was cancelled or not - after all, something else must have caused the cancellation if all you have are synchronous methods. Depending on what the cancellation means, returning an error, an empty result, false or throwing an exception (but probably not `OperationCancelledException` anyway!) might each make their sense - you need to tailor it to the kind of interface you're making.

Comment: I'm actually interested in the case where the method is async, and goofed in writing the question. I have updated it accordingly. Can you focus your answer on that case?

Comment: @ObliviousSage The first part of the answer is still relevant. If you don't throw, then the task won't transition to Canceled state. Is that an issue for you? Do you want the caller to be able to know that you stopped in the middle of what you were doing? Only you can answer that

Comment: @Luaan `An unhandled OperationCancelledException in a task will cancel the Task's cancellation token as well (if any).` afaik, it will not. When the OperationCancelledException is thrown, the task will check the associated cancellation token. If it is the same as the one attached to the task, the task transitions to Canceled. Otherwise, the task transitions to Faulted. The task cannot change the status of a CancellationToken (only the owner of the CancellationTokenSource can)

Comment: @KevinGosse It's in the documentation for `OperationCancelledException`: "If the task that was canceled had an associated cancellation token, it is returned by the CancellationToken property, and the CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested property of the token is set to true."

Comment: @ObliviousSage If you're in a `Task`, absolutely do the throw. It's necessary for the proper composition of tasks. Not that you necessarily notice you're doing anything wrong - `await` doesn't use task continuations.